# Баг в bootstrap, как пофиксить?

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Добрый вечер!
В Bootstrap есть такая функция как data-size , которая определяет, сколько строк выводить при нажатии на выпадающий список.
Суть бага вот в чём: при медленном интернете, data-size словно выключен, т.к. всё содержимое в выпадающем списке выдаётся в огромном размере (чтобы было понятнее, в выпадающем списке 50 строк, а хотя data-size="5"). Как это фиксить?

Comment: Пробуйте отображать блок после полной загрузки страницы

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш [mcve]